Automatic log out while working in Cent OS Stream 8
While I am working, the device automatically log outs and shows the login screen. When I logged in, all my work got lost. Basically I am using terminal, firefox, sometime terminator app. Skype from flatpak remain open in the background. Sometime while moving cursor and sometimes while typing it automatically logouts.
Frequency : 3-4 times a day. OS : Centos Stream 8 Device: Desktop Processor: Intel i7 12700
Note: I don't have root access.
I tried to see log file /var/log/message for something like this. There, nothing is written related to logout.

my two cents:
you may need to set the environment variable TMOUT to 0
into the system file
/etc/profile.d/local.sh

for further info you can read this question and the accepted answer.
(while for further info on the environment variable TMOUT you can see the bash man page)
